# How do I center UIBarButtonItem with custom look?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

Alright, so I have a TableView in one of my Views in my iPhone app.  I'm using a UINavigationController, so using that I created the UIToolBar at the bottom of the table.  Works great.  However, I want the items in the toolbar to resemble how the Facebook app has them:

[image: UIToolbar]

Not only would I like the Buttons (I will have only 2) to resemble those. (They connect when touching another button), but I really want to show the user what "Tab" they are on.  In the image above, it is obvious to the user they are on the Wall.  When they touch "Info", it becomes darkened and the user knows where they are.  Does anyone know how they did it so my app may also have *clear* navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have on a picture is standard `UISegmentControl` with `UISegmentedControlStyleBar` style - you can use it.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see.  I was looking in the completely wrong direction on how to do this.  That works perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `UISegmentedControl` like they did